# How to use sha password to connect to Suds client

Tags: python, django, suds

I have a Django app and within that app I have a script that uses Suds to create a client.  Now the user is authenticated through SSO and I have access to the user/password string in encrypted form.

For example:

```
'{SSHA}LvvpOnu1UZ/be9kmcdDb0Sgkzv2ObkcTlCMYIw=='
```

It's encrypted using SHA algorithm.  Is it possible to pass this value to Suds to create the client, and if so how?  Here's my suds code:

```
""" 
Get xml representation of the object.
@return: The root node.
@rtype: L{Element}
"""
root = Element('UsernameToken', ns=wssens)
u = Element('Username', ns=wssens)
u.setText(self.username)
root.append(u)
p = Element('Password', ns=wssens)
p.setText(self.password)
# <--------------- new code here ------------------->
p.set('Type', 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/'
      'oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText')
# <------------------------------------------------->
root.append(p)
if self.nonce is not None:
    n = Element('Nonce', ns=wssens)
    n.setText(self.nonce)
    root.append(n)
if self.created is not None:
    n = Element('Created', ns=wsuns)
    n.setText(str(UTC(self.created)))
    root.append(n)
return root
```

Comment: isn't it better to use a library instead of creating xml by hand ? like so : https://fedorahosted.org/suds/

Comment: if it's [SHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm) then it's not encrypted, it's hashed... hashing is a one-way operation, you can't recover the plain-text password from it